# Error: AH00543: httpd: bad user name - Xampp / Apache

Tags: apache, webserver, xampp, localhost

I hope you're good, this seems like a great resource and I'd really like your help if possible. It would be greatly appreciated.

Xampp and Apache were working fine for me for the past few days and since restarting my computer I am getting the following error:

Starting Apache Web Server...
Exit code: 8
Stdout:
apache config test fails, aborting
Stderr:
AH00543: httpd: bad user name ccda

I have tried multiple solutions, but it appears there is a user name error in the config file. The only problem is I don't know how to fix this.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 6):

(Sorry for such a delayed post, but this may be helpful for other's search)

Just go to the httpd.conf file in XAMPP and find

User daemon

Group daemon

If the user is not daemon, change it to daemon, worked for me.

Comment: Years later and this helped me! Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You need to update `httpd.conf` file. Run the following command to open Apache configuration file `httpd.conf`:

```
sudo gedit /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf
```

Then, search <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> for `User` word until you will see the following:

```
user abc(any word)
Group abc(any word)
</ifmodule>
```

Replace `user` and `group` in a following way:

```
User nobody
Group Nobody
</ifmodule>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but letters of Nobody have to be lowercase ( nobody not Nobody )

Answer (score 2):

Only replace

User daemon
Group daemon

by

User "your username of linux"
Group "your username of linux"

Comment: Can't do that - `WSGI process blocked from running as root.`

Answer (score 1):

1. Navigate to **/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf**

Change **User daemon** to **User your-linux-username**

For me it's under LoadModule list

2. You may want to change as well **/opt/lampp/etc/proftpd.conf**

**User daemon** to **User your-linux-username**

Answer (score 0):

Just take a look into .conf file,

```
find directives 
User
Group
```

(usualy after words: "If you wish httpd to run as a different" in config file)

and fill values with your system usernames.

- For ubuntu

  ```
  User www-data
  Group www-data
  ```
- For CentOS

  ```
  User apache
  ```

and so on